# Why does a checkbox not remain checked in IE but not in FF or Chrome

Tags: firefox, checkbox

i will make myself clear hope it will help to solve my problem

In my search engine i have the option to search some subjects from check box...it is like i have 10 check box with an option to choose some of the 10 check box and then to press search and i need to see some results....

now in IE after I press the search button i can see the results...

in FF after i press the search button the page load and it clear all check box i choose, and i need to choose it again....

hope i make my self clear sorry for my poor English

Comment: When you press the search button, are you going to another page? If so, are you sending information about which boxes are checked to the new page?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like normal behaviour. You will need to add `checked` to every check box you want checked, the browser is not going to do that for you based on previous selections.

The only exception to this rule is that Firefox will populate input elements with the previous values when you reload the page. You can't rely on this behaviour, though, and you should always use `checked`.